# How to get different superscript of numbers for authors in elsarticle

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, elsarticle

I have the authors' names and I want their address/affiliation to be referenced below the page, but I get the same superscript of 1 for both authors but I want different numbers or characters. (P.S. Prior to this, I had an error on hyper ref and I changed my code.)

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{setspace} 
 \doublespacing
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title of article}

\author[add1]{Jack\texorpdfstring{\corref{cor1}}{}}
\ead{aa@aa.com}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding Author}
\fntext[fn1]{aa@aa.com}

\author[add2]{Alice}
\ead{bb@bb.com}
\fntext[fn2]{bbbbb@b.com}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

My output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

The `elsarticle` assume that affiliations follow the names, but you can manually add the footnote reference:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title of article}

\author{Jack\fnref{fn1}\texorpdfstring{\corref{cor1}}{}}
\ead{aa@aa.com}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding Author}
\fntext[fn1]{aa@aa.com}

\author{Alice\fnref{fn2}}
\ead{bb@bb.com}
\fntext[fn2]{bbbbb@b.com}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```